# Getting line number of error in main.asc ( Flash Media Server )

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-media-server

It's very difficult to debug an error in Main.asc, as the log only shows a text "Compilation Error".
How to get the line number, where the error actually occured?

The log just shows this :
    #Version: 1.0

```
#Start-Date: 2012-08-02 00:27:48

#Software: Adobe Flash Media Server 4.0.0 r1121 x86

#Date: 2012-08-02

#Fields: date   time    x-pid   x-status    x-ctx   x-comment

2012-08-02  00:27:48    4524    (e)2641277  Sending error message: Compilation error    -

#Date: 2012-08-02
```

V.

Comment: well, it was just a + missing between two string meant for concatenation. But it was very hard to figure it out. My main.asc is around 150 lines... and i had to remove and add each function one by one.. for just this silly error :(

Comment: Yea, that's why in my experience it's usually malformed code that gives you that error.  A tip is in the future run your code through a javascript code checker like jslint.com.   Once your code isn't malformed the Flash media server is OK to debug as it gives you line numbers for run-time errors - as per my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe there is a way for compilation errors.  Runtime Errors will show line numbers in the log/admin console.

You likely have malformed code - an extra or missing { or the like.

Try running your code through jslint.com (or similiar code checker) as an easy way to weed malformed code errors.